# Why flask redirect gives me a blank page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

This is my redirect route:

```
from flask import Api, Resource
from flask import Blueprint, redirect

users_blueprint = Blueprint('users', __name__, template_folder='')
api = Api(users_blueprint)

@users_blueprint.route('/signout')
def signout():
    if not session['user_id']:
        return redirect('/')
    del session['user_id']
    return redirect('/')


class LandingPage(Resource):

    def get(self):
        return render_template('index.html')


api.add_resource(LandingPage, '/')
```

I'm getting no errors. The `'/'` route renders just fine but I can't redirect to it from the `signout()` function. It just gives me a blank page.

Comment: What does it say in the url bar after the redirect when the page is blank?

Comment: It just says `localhost:3000/signout`. Which makes me think that when I click on Signout it won't reach Flask endpoint because Flask is running on port 5000. I'm making a React app hence you see port 3000.

Comment: So when you go to `localhost:5000/signout` it will redirect you to `localhost:3000/signout` correct?